# Tensorflow: How to make return value of tf.unique same size as input

Tags: python, tensorflow

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique, `tf.unique(x)` returns a tuple `(y, idx)`,  The **shape of y is (?, )** is not known during build time. Is there anyway I can pad `y` to match the input size `x`?.

For example,

```
# tensor 'x' is [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8]
y, idx = unique(x)
y ==> [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
idx ==> [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

I wanna make y = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.pad` to pad the zeros after calling `tf.unique`.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None))
y, idx = tf.unique(x)
y = tf.pad(y,[[0,(tf.shape(x) - tf.shape(y))[0]]])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run(y, {x:np.random.randint(0,10, (10), dtype=np.int32)}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your need separate treatment the problem.

```
y = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
idx = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]

for ii in range(0, len(idx) - len(y)):
    y.append(0)

print(y)
```

The output is

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

use set to find the unique ..diff the len and append trailing 0

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8]
length = len(x)

print(length)
y = list(set(x))

print(y)
pad = length - len(list(set(x)))

for index in range(0,pad):
    y.append(0)


print(y)
```

Output

```
9
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```